How Hamming Distance changes with added vector
Suppose we have $k$ vectors, $v_1, \dots, v_k$, where $v_i = (v_{i,1}, \dots, v_{i,n})$, all of the same length $n$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. We can construct a matrix $V$:
\begin{equation}
V = \begin{pmatrix}
v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & \dots & v_{1,n} \\
v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & \dots & v_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \dots & \vdots \\
v_{k,1} & v_{k,2} & \dots & v_{k,n}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
We consider the span of the vectors, $\langle v_1, \dots, v_k\rangle$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and find the Minimum Hamming Distance of all possible vectors. Suppose the Minimum Hamming Distance of these vectors is $d_V \in \mathbb{N}_0$, which can be found with the Brouwer-Zimmermann Algorithm.
Suppose we add another vector $v_{k+1} = (v_{k+1,1}, \dots, v_{k+1, n})$ to the span.
We can then consider the new matrix:
\begin{equation}
V' = \begin{pmatrix}
v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & \dots & v_{1,n} \\
v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & \dots & v_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \dots & \vdots \\
v_{k,1} & v_{k,2} & \dots & v_{k,n} \\
v_{k+1,1} & v_{k+1, 2} & \dots & v_{k+1, n}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is there a way to calculate the Minimum Hamming Distance $d_{V'}$ of the span of the rows of $V'$ without having to use the Brouwer Zimmermann Algorithm entirely? That is, is there a shorter way, or must be brute force the Brouwer Zimmermann Algorithm again?

Hint: the minimum distance cannot increase by adding another row; it either remains the same, or is smaller.  Also, perhaps reading the first few chapters of a book on coding theory might help; finding the minimum distance of a code is NP-hard, as is even finding the minimum distance approximately, see e.g. this webpage
